# Paypal Express Order Review Page

Tags: checkout, paypal, ce-1.6.2.0, paypal-express

I've recently turned on Paypal Express Checkout on my Magento site, during testing I noticed that once the transaction is completed in Paypal the customer is redirected back to a final order confirmation page on my website.

Research told me that this was due to the "pass shipping options to Paypal" option as well as my cart/basket page not being HTTPS.

After having enabled SSL on the cart, Paypal is still redirecting customers back to my website to complete the transaction.

Can this be avoided? Is there a way for the customer to complete their entire transaction on Paypal and simply to return to my website for the "Order Complete" page?

Comment: See http://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2016/10/remove-review-page-in-magento-paypal.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anton is right: PayPal Express is designed to work this way (redirect to Paypal, then redirect to your website again). One reason is for example, that your business terms etc. must be shown to the customer before he finally agrees to buy.

There is - of course - another possibility: You could use Website Payments Standard. The customer will be redirected to PayPal after he confirmed your business terms and pays there.
Bad about this: I was told by PayPal staff members, that Website Payments Standard is an "old standard" and "redirects most of the time"; we see several cases where the payment is confirmed by the customer, but the IPN won't show im Magento backend.

Ask further if u need more detail :)

Answer (score 4):

Paypal Express Checkout is a checkout method (don't mix with payment method that other paypal methods are) and goes for authorisation to paypal website, get's the authorisation and user billing details and redirects you back to finish the checkout in paypal express checkout page.

This is how it works, you can set the action to be "sale" instead of "authorisation" but it will still redirect you back to Paypal express Checkout page in Magento to finish the order placement.

see additional information from Magento knowledge base :

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/getting-started-with-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/paypal-express-checkout-workflow-for-magento-community
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community

Comment: Exactly, Paypal Express Checkout is a checkout method not a payment method.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use Paypal Express (and there are good business reasons why - lower transaction fees), try this answer given on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313748/336905. We are about to try that ourselves.